# Sencha Architect svn IDE

Tags: extjs

I was just wondering is there any SVN plugin for sencha Architech. How can I use source control with sencha Architect To check in and check out files from architect?

Answer (score 1):

No SVN plugin for sencha Architech.
Use TortoiseSVN and commit files in file explore.